# What do I need to reload after a device reset?

Tags: directx11

Is there a complete list of resources that need to be reloaded after a device reset? I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Also, should I reload them from disk each time, or do I want to make in-memory copies?

Comment: You tagged this for D3D11, which does not have the concept of a "lost device" that D3D9 did. Did you actually mean to ask about D3D9?

Comment: @JoshPetrie I did mean D3D11. So I don't have to deal with device resets at all anymore? Sweet!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

D3D11 does not have a "device lost" concept, at least not one like D3D9 had (with it's related "on-lost" and "on-reset" management).

DXGI, which you'll use with D3D10+, has [error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the device being physically removed and one for a reset due to a bad command, but these require very different handling.